# Merging json files using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to merge two json files using command "jq -s . file1 file2". But I want these file's content to be comma separated, neither it should start with [].

file 1:

```
{
  "node1": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node2": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  }
}
```

file 2:

```
{
  "node3": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node4": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  }
}
```

**Output using jq -s . file 1 file 2**

```
[
    {
      "node1": {
        "Environment": "PRD",
        "OS": "linux"
      },
      "node2": {
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "OS": "linux"
      }
    },
    {
      "node3": {
        "Environment": "PRD",
        "OS": "linux"
      },
      "node4": {
        "Environment": "NPR",
        "OS": "linux"
      }
    }
]
```

**Required output:**

```
{
  "node1": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node2": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
    "node3": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node4": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help in finding the solution. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477547/how-to-combine-the-sequence-of-objects-in-jq-into-one-object

Answer (score 1):

```
$ jq -s 'add' file[12].json
{
  "node1": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node2": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node3": {
    "Environment": "PRD",
    "OS": "linux"
  },
  "node4": {
    "Environment": "NPR",
    "OS": "linux"
  }
}
```

Using `add` will concatenate the top-level keys in the list that is slurped in from the files, creating a merged object of those keys.